# How can i use a global variable in a If on angular .ts like JavaScript inside a component

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Look this issue. 
How can i use in the IF statement a value which is setted up on a function. I think i need to set up the function as global using let but is not working Thanks for your time.

Here the code where the issue popup.

The issue is in the variable valueSiorNo.

Thanks!

```
/**         changeValue         */
public  changeValue(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
     var valueSiorNo = event.target.value;
}



/**         setConfirmation     */
public setConfirmation(event, current = this.confirmation) {
    const wizard = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('wizard'));

    if( (wizard[0]["CAPITAL_PESOS"] ==  event.target.value) && ( ( valueSiorNo != null )))  {
        this.confirmation = false;
        this.mal = true;
        this.cap = true;

    }

    else{
        this.mal = false;
        this.confirmation = true;
        this.cap = true;

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `valueSiorNo` is part of `changeValue` and hence it's scope is restricted to this function and cannot be used inside `setConfirmation` function.

You need to make it a class member:

```
class MyClass {
    valueSiorNo: any
    constructor() { }

    changeValue(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value);
        this.valueSiorNo = event.target.value;
    }

    /**         setConfirmation     */
    public setConfirmation(event, current = this.confirmation) {

        // access this.valueSiorNo in here

    }

}
```